# Always show date input calendar that takes up whole div

Tags: javascript, html, css, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I'm using ASP.NET Core 2.2 MVC and I have a page containing a date input. When the page loads, I would like it to have the calendar always kept open by default without needing to click the little arrow:

[image]

If that's possible, can the arrow be removed as well? I'd still want the text box to be there for manual input.

I also want the calendar always take up the height and width of its parent div. If the div's height is relative, the calendar would stretch as it needs to.

The solution I'm looking for doesn't need to be solved exactly this way, and I'm open to plug-ins. I've tried [JQuery UI datepicker](https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/) but I haven't gotten it to work the way I want to. One thing to note is that I have `asp-for` attribute on the input tag.

HTML:

```
<div id="wapper">
    <input asp-for="@Model.DatePicked" type="date" required />
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#wrapper {
   height: 20vh;
   width: 20vw;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use JQuery UI datepicker:

> I would like it to have the calendar always kept open by default without needing to click the little arrow

You can use inline mode, it display the datepicker embedded in the page instead of in an overlay. Simply call .datepicker() on a div instead of an input.

```
$("#datepicker").datepicker();
```

Because you call datepicker in div it always keep it open as you wish

```
<div id="datepicker"></div>
```

.

> If that's possible, can the arrow be removed as well? I'd still want the text box to be there for manual input.

With inline mode there is not any arrow and if you want to show date in textbox:

```
<input type="text" id="alternate">

$("#datepicker").datepicker({
  altField: "#alternate"
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! The only reason JQuery UI wasn't a perfect fit is because I had struggle with having it resize correctly. The width resizes fine but not the height. Do you know how it could be made to resize dynamically?

Comment: @Lukas, Yes you can customize styles of datepicker, change width of it and increase size of each cell of table with css or dynamically with js:  [see here](https://jsfiddle.net/7tfs5L8y/)

Comment: The width does work, but if you adjust, say, `height: 250px;`, you will see it doesn't resize properly. The buttons are also stretched and become really thin.

Comment: You shoud not set height to fix number, just increase the padding of `TD`s, see my link in last comment

Comment: Okay, I see what you mean now. I think it's better to increase the padding of the anchors so that they aren't really small to click on. But this should work, thank you for your help!